# Trying to write an Integer value through node js socket, but can't do that

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

Am trying to post some string from my tcp client to tcp server(Both were implemented using NodeJS). Once I receive message from client I need to write some integer value in the same socket. But when I tried writing the integer value, am getting an exception saying "Invalid Data". Can you please help me to understand or fix this.

**Server Code:**

```
var net = require('net');  
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';  
var PORT = 6969;  
net.createServer(function(sock) {  
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);  
    sock.on('data', function(data) {  
        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);  
        sock.write(data.length);  
    });  
    sock.on('close', function(data) {  
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);  
    });  
}).listen(PORT, HOST);  
console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

**Client Code**

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';  
var PORT = 6969;  

var client = new net.Socket();  
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {  
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);  
    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');  
});  

client.on('data', function(data) {  
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);  
    client.destroy();  
});  

client.on('close', function() {  
    console.log('Connection closed');  
});
```

**Output:**

> CONNECTED: 127.0.0.1:56183   DATA 127.0.0.1: I am Chuck Norris!
>
> net.js:612
>       throw new TypeError('invalid data');

Comment: Can i show your code for sending integer value?

Comment: @HirenS. I think he thinks this is that code, `sock.write(data.length);`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yep! I am trying to write that length of the message which server received, to client socket.

Comment: @abineshs How many bytes do you think that sends? What do you think those bytes contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output says it all, invalid data!

`request.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])`

`The chunk argument should be a Buffer or a string.`

`sock` is `Stream`, you can write Buffer or string into stream.

You should read the documentation of nodejs here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding_callback

What are you trying to achieve, communication between processes?

Comment: I am running a TCP Server implemented using NodeJS. The TCP Clients are written in python script. That script expects an Integer value from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var writeBuffer = Buffer(1);
writeBuffer[0] = 1; //Value to send
.
.
client.write(writeBuffer);
```